# How to prove differentiability of the following unknown function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

We have $f:\Bbb{R}^n\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^m$ s.t $f(x)=o(\|x-x_0\|)$, and I have to prove $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

So by definition, I know that $f$ is differentiable if there exists a linear transformation $L_{x_0}$ s.t $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-L_{x_0}(x-x_0) }{\|x-x_0\|}=0$. Also I know that $L_{x_0}(x-x_0)$ satisfies $L_{x_0}(x-x_0)\in O(\|x-x_0\|)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if and only if there is a linear transformation $L_{x_0}$ such that

$$f(x)-f(x_0)-L_{x_0}(x-x_0)\in o(\Vert x-x_0\Vert).$$

It's really just a slight reformulation of your definition. Now if $f\in o(\Vert x-x_0\Vert)$, then you'll quickly see that this condition is fulfilled.

Comment: I can't see exactly, why is this condition fulfilled? I know nothing about $f(x_0)$ nor $L_{x_0}$.

Comment: $f(x_0)$ is determined by $f\in o(\Vert x-x_0\Vert)$ and you are allowed to *choose* $L_{x_0}$ such that your condition is fulfilled. Consider that you want $f(x_0)$ and $L_{x_0}$ such that $f(x)\in o(\Vert x-x_0\Vert)$ iff $f(x)-f(x_0)-L_{x_0}(x-x_0)\in o(\Vert x-x_0\Vert)$.

Comment: Thing is I can't understand why I'm allowed to choose such linear transformation. Doesn't it have to be the Jacobian matrix? If you care to elaborate a little more it would be very helpful, and thank you for the explanation

Comment: You can choose because that's how the definition works. It's not "I give you a matrix and that matrix has to fulfill the condition". It's "Find me a matrix that fulfills the condition". Of course, you can then prove that *if* you can find such a matrix, it's automatically the Jacobian. But this just means that $L_{x_0}$ determines what the Jacobian is, so finding $L_{x_0}$ is a way of finding the Jacobian. Or finding the Jacobian is a way of finding $L_{x_0}$. Depending on which one is easier to find. In this case, that's $L_{x_0}$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos As you said its "Find me a matrix that fulfills the condition". Can you please show how you find such matrix?

Comment: You already know that $f(x)\in o(\Vert x-x_0\Vert)$. From this it follows that $f(x_0)=0$ (technically speaking, continuity at $x_0$ is also required, which seems to be missing from your exercise). So we already have that $f(x)-f(x_0)\in o(\Vert x-x_0\Vert)$, since it's just equal to $f(x)$. Now how could a map $L_{x_0}$ look such that $f(x)-f(x_0)-L_{x_0}(x-x_0)\in o(\Vert x-x_0\Vert)$, given that we already know that $f(x)-f(x_0)\in o(\Vert x-x_0\Vert)$?

Comment: @Vercassicelaunos why does $f(x) \in o(||x-x_0||) $ implies $f(x_0)=0$ ?

Comment: Continuity of $f$ at $x_0$ is required for this. Then $f(x)\to f(x_0)$ if $x\to x_0$. Now if $\frac{f(x)}{\Vert x-x_0\Vert}\to0$ as $x\to x_0$, then $f(x)$ must go to $0$, since $\Vert x-x_0\Vert\to0$. But whatever $f(x)$ goes to as $x\to x_0$, that number must be $f(x_0)$, otherwise $f$ wouldn't be continuous.

Comment: To show that continuity is really required, take the function $f(x)=1$ for $x=x_0$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. This function is $o(\Vert x-x_0\Vert)$, but it's obviously not differentiable at $x_0$, since it's not even continuous.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos But op didn’t mention anything about continuity

Comment: @FreeZe: I know, but without continuity the statement as given is false. Which is what I wanted to show with my last comment.